# PC specs for running a VM lab with VirtualBox

Tags: laptop, memory, ssd, virtual-machines

I am about to get a laptop where I am going to use VirtualBox to run my VM lab (more VMs at the same time).

I was thinking about to get an i7 8th gen.(4 Cores) with 64GB RAM.

Do you think that would be enough or it's better to get a more recent processor like an i7 11th/12th gen like the Intel Core i7-12700H?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to do in the VMs, Intel 8th gen is way outdated. Try to get one with Intel 12/13th gen or AMD Ryzen 5000 or 7000 series. Assuming you don't want to pay a super high premium for the extra RAM and storage I would reccomend the latest revision of the Framework laptop (both 13 and 16 should be good for your use case) and put in the RAM and SSD yourself

Comment: Hi, basically Malware analysis and Reverse Engineering.  I was thinking about an MSI Laptop with max 64Gb of RAM and a 12th gen. (don't know if I can say the model here ). Thank you

Comment: I just had a look to the Framework Laptop, interesting product.  I was more into the MSI katana laptop (talking about price range). Thanks again

Comment: You can say the model here that you are looking into, but preferably as an edit of your question so it looks more logical for future people going here

Comment: Basically I was thinking about an MSI Katana GF66 with a recent processor, lot of RAM (up to 64 GB) and a good graphic card (non exactly for gaming, more for Pentesting), but my OS would be Linux (Linux Mint or Ubuntu) so I am still not sure about my choice. I would eventually  virtualize Windows using VirtualBox. Thanks